# Problem with ship overlapping in 2D-arrays for Battleships game, Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I am creating a simple console-based Battleships in Java, for people who is unfamiliar with the game, it's played on a 2D-grid where you can put down different sized ships either horizontally or vertically. In my example it is a 10x10 grid created by using a 2D char-array. The ships are NOT allowed to overlap each other, they can't share the same 1x1 grid.

I have managed to fix so they can't overlap each other, but the problem I have is if a ship share the same column or row (depending on if the ship is placed vertically or horizontally) at the STARTING POSITION, I can't place it down.

See example picture below for better understanding.

['0' is "empty" slots, 'S' is current placed ships(3-sized). I can place (in this example) 4-sized ships at blue markers, but I can't place them like the red markers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFrLK.png)

```
    public void placeShip(ShipType shipType, int posX, int posY, int shipSize, Placement placement) {
    boolean success = true;
    char tempChar = 'x';

    if(shipType == ShipType.BATTLESHIP)
        tempChar = 'B';
    else if(shipType == ShipType.CARRIER)
        tempChar = 'C';
    else if(shipType == ShipType.DESTROYER)
        tempChar = 'D';
    else if(shipType == ShipType.SUBMARINE)
        tempChar = 'S';


    if(placement == Placement.HORIZONTAL) {

        for(int i = 0; i < posX+shipSize; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < posX+shipSize; j++) {
                if(board[i][posX-1] != '0' || board[posY-1][i] != '0') {
                    System.out.println("Can't place down the ship ");
                    success = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if(success) {
            System.out.println("Got space");
            for(int i = 0; i < shipSize; i++) {
                board[posY-1][posX-1+i] = tempChar;
                success = false;
            }
        }
    }

    if(placement == Placement.VERTICAL) {
        for(int i = 0; i < posY+shipSize; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < posX+shipSize; j++) {
                if(board[posY-1][i] != '0' || board[i][posX-1] != '0') {
                    System.out.println("Can't place down the ship ");
                    success = false;
                    break;
                }                   
            }
        }

        if(success) {
            System.out.println("Got space");
            for(int i = 0; i < shipSize; i++) {
                board[posY-1+i][posX-1] = tempChar;
                success = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above is the code I use to place ships, where I send in Position X and Y and the size of the ship, and the direction of the ship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-think your loops for checking if a ship can be placed down. Let's break down one of them into plain English:

```java
if(placement == Placement.HORIZONTAL) {
  for(int i = 0; i < posX+shipSize; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < posX+shipSize; j++) {
      if(board[i][posX-1] != '0' || board[posY-1][i] != '0') {
        System.out.println("Can't place down the ship ");
        success = false;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

**First issue:**

```
for(int i = 0; i < posX+shipSize; i++)
```

Why are we iterating from 0 to `posX`+`shipSize`? we only need to check `shipSize` spaces. So you should be looping from `posX` to `posX`+`shipSize`, or from 0 to `shipSize`, not a combination.

**Second issue:**

Despite your position being horizontal or vertical, you are nesting your for loops. Which means you're doing your loop `shipSize` times for no reason. You only need to do it once.

**Third issue:**

```java
if(board[i][posX-1] != '0' || board[posY-1][i] != '0')
```

The position `board[i][posX-1]` *has no meaning* in this context, and *is not related to the position of your ship*, because **you always start at `i = 0`**. So no matter where you're trying to place your ship, if you have one in the same row or col, we have a problem. **This is what's causing the issue in your question.** Instead, it should be something like: `if(board[posY-1][posX-1] != '0')`.

Lastly, why not just set the position of `posX` and `posY` properly? So you don't have to subtract 1 and confuse yourself.

Ultimately, your new block should look something like this *(but I can't be sure since you didn't post a minimum reproducible example)*:

```
if(placement == Placement.HORIZONTAL) {
  for(int i = 0; i < shipSize; i++) {
    if(board[posY-1][posX-1+i] != '0') {
      System.out.println("Can't place down the ship ");
      success = false;
      break;
    }
  }

  // your code
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it helped solve it for me. I got so confused and flustered by it all, I have tried so many stuff and I guess I just added unecessary stuff to it.